# convert alert() to sweetAlert() - javascript

Tags: javascript, sweetalert

I am trying to convert **alert()** to **sweetAlert()**  in this portion of code:

```
if (ttlpg > 0) {

    if (resultSaveParameters == true && resultSaveImage == true) {
        //more code
    } else {
        $('#loadingdivmain').hide('fast');
        alert("Upload Error.");
    }

} else {
    //this should alert
    sweetAlert('Sorry', 'No image(s) to save', 'error');
}
```

I am using **sweetAlert()** in the same js file on other parts of the coding, and it is working fine.

[Here](https://limonte.github.io/sweetalert2/) is the source I am using.

Comment: Perhaps you can describe the issue you are having.

Answer (score 0):

As documented in the link you provided for `sweetAlert`, you call it by referring to `swal` and not `sweetAlert`.

Your code should be:

```
swal('Sorry', 'No image(s) to save', 'error');
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have tried setting ttlpg <= 0, then check your script link to SweetAlert2. It's possible that your downloaded files aren't in the same directory or the link to those files is misspelled or improperly placed.

Your links should look like this,

```
<script src="dist/sweetalert2.min.js"></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dist/sweetalert2.css">
```

And according to the reference, sweet alert needs to be called like this,

```
swal({   
title: 'Error!',   
text: 'Do you want to continue',   
type: 'error',   
confirmButtonText: 'Cool' 
});
```